# Android CircularFloatingActionMenu SlideDown

Tags: android, animation, floating-action-button

I am using this: [CircularFloatingActionMenu](https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu/)

I have been able to use it so far pretty well. I am able to move it to desired positions as described in the ReadMe and even set rotation, theme coloring etc. My problem is I am trying to create a custom animation so that when placed in the upper right the icons shoot downwards. I kind of cheated and got it to appear to work by setting the start/end angle at 89 and 90 degrees so instead of being in a line they are just slightly off, but my problem is that when the animation finishes the final position ends up stacking all the icons on top of one another. I have attached screenshot demonstrating this.[image: before final]

[image: after final]

Ive called my SlideDownAnimationHandler.java class as such:

```
  FloatingActionMenu actionMenuTopRight = new FloatingActionMenu.Builder(this)
            .setStartAngle(89)
            .setEndAngle(90)

            .setAnimationHandler(new SlideDownAnimationHandler())
            .addSubActionView(rLSubBuilder.setContentView(rlIcon1).build())
            .addSubActionView(rLSubBuilder.setContentView(rlIcon2).build())
            .addSubActionView(rLSubBuilder.setContentView(rlIcon3).build())
            //.addSubActionView(rLSubBuilder.setContentView(rlIcon4).build())
            //.addSubActionView(rLSubBuilder.setContentView(rlIcon5).build())
            .attachTo(darkButton)
            .build();
```

I don't really want to post the SlideDownAnimationHandler.java classify as it is quite large (~100 lines of code). I'm wondering if theres a better way to properly animate the slide down effect, and also how to set their final position in a similar fashion to how i set the y translation in the animation itself.